# Confusion about as ... as clause

Tags: comparison

Here is the original sentence:

> The publisher's alterations to a book are difficult for a writer, ***as
>   is the book creation as the book grows.***

Could anyone help explain how the second clause is relevant to the first one? Also point out what kind of grammar it shows. It seems like a comparison between the book creation and the alterations to books. My attempt to paraphrase:

> When the book grows, the publisher's alterations to a book are ***as
>   difficult as the book creation is for a writer.***

Comment: Yes, your phrasing is much clearer. Looking at the sentence as originally written, I could not fathom why the book would still be in "creation" _while it grows_.  But on re-reading,  it seems to me that the sentence is trying to describe a situation where the writer sends s manuscript to the publisher in pieces as he goes along, so he is still "creating" while the earlier parts are being edited.

Comment: I can certainly relate to the viewpoint expressed in the sentence. As a writer, I agree that dealing with my publisher's edits was much more time-consuming than writing the book. Their edits were horribly amateurish; most had to be undone. Basically, I ended up telling them to keep their hands off it, and edited it myself. Same with cover design. They were useless.

Comment: @Hung Tran: But the original sentence is not really an example of "as..as" , so your rephrasing does not have the same meaning as the original. The two difficulties are not being compared and are not being judged to be of equal hardship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different uses of *as*. In the first one it means *so is, just like ... is* and should be interpreted like this:

> - The publisher's alterations to a book are difficult for a writer, **and so is** is the book creation as the book grows.
> - The publisher's alterations to a book are difficult for a writer, **just like** is the book creation **is difficult** as the book grows.

The second *as* has the meaning of *while, during the time that* or *the more*:

> - The publisher's alterations to a book are difficult for a writer, as is the book creation **while** the book grows.
> - The publisher's alterations to a book are difficult for a writer, as is the book creation **the more** the book grows.

So you see how the first *as* is used for **comparison** while the second one is **temporal** or expresses the degree or extent.